# XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange behaving strangely

Tags: javascript

I have a function called urlExists that I used in several projects without problem. Now I'm in a patients panel and need to check if a js file exists before call a function addEventListener:

```
function urlExists(url){
   var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
   http.open('HEAD', url, false);
   http.onreadystatechange = function(){
       if(request.readyState==4){
           return true;
       }else{
           return false;
       }
   }
}
//other part of code

   if (urlExists('../../medvoice/speaker.js')){
      beep.addEventListener('ended', function() {
       var parameters = {
         target: dados,
         tts: {
            name: 'lianetts'
         },
         binder: 'speak',
          path: {
           name: '../../medvoice/mediapool/',
           link: '/medhosphsl/medvoice/mediapool/'
         }
       };                                                                                                                                               
       var speaker = new Speaker(parameters);
    });
   }
```

When a put console log inside urlExists, console shows the test phrase, but inside onreadystatechange don't.I'm missing something?

Comment: `onreadystatechange` is a callback ... what you return from it is not being returned from `urlExists` function (despite you making a **synchronous** request) - therefore `urlExists` is returning `undefined` - as there is no return statement, therefore `if (urlExists('../../medvoice/speaker.js'))` is not true

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems:

1. Your `return true` and `return false` aren't returning from `urlExists`, they're returning from the `onreadystatechange` callback. `urlExists` has no explicit `return` anywhere, so calling it always results in `undefined`.
2. You never call `send` to fire the request.
3. You're using `readyState` to decide whether the resource exists, but that just tells you the state of the request; you should be checking `status`.

If you *must* use a synchronous request, you don't need or want an `onreadystatechange` handler at all. Here's a version with all those issues addressed:

```
function urlExists(url){
   var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
   http.open('HEAD', url, false);
   http.send();
   return http.status === 200;
}
```

---

For completeness: Synchronous ajax request make for poor UX and may well be phased out entirely at some point. Instead, use an asynchronous request and have `urlExists` return a promise:

```
function urlExists(url){
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open('HEAD', url);
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (http.readyState === 4) {
                resolve(http.status === 200);
            }
        };
        http.send();
    });
}

// Usage:
urlExists("some-url").then(function(exists) {
    console.log("Exists? " + exists);
});
```

Or the more modern way with [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) and ES2015+ arrow functions:

```
function urlExists(url) {
    return fetch(url, {method: "HEAD"}).then(response => response.ok);
}

// Usage:
urlExists("some-url").then(exists => console.log("Exists? " + exists));
```

Or we could embrace ES2017 (out next month!):

```
async function urlExists(url) {
    return (await fetch(url, {method: "HEAD"})).ok;
}

// Usage (in another async function):
console.log("Exists? " + await urlExists("some-url"));
```

---

Side note: `urlExists` will only work for URLs you can access via ajax, so typically only ones in the same origin. If that's your use case, great, but I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Crowder, thanks for the perspective! I'll try, makes sense.